# Why do I get a Encoding::CompatibilityError with #inspect?

Tags: ruby, encoding, inspect

The following code works without problem:

```
#encoding: utf-8
class Text
  def initialize(txt)
    @txt = txt
  end
  def inspect
    "<Text: %s>" % @txt
  end
end

p Text.new('Hello World')
```

But if I try `p Text.new('Hä, was soll das?')` I get a Encoding::CompatibilityError:

```
inspect_with_umlaut.rb:26:in `p': inspected result must be ASCII only or use the default external encoding (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
  from inspect_with_umlaut.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

Why this?

And more important: How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message explains already the why:
*inspected result must be ASCII only or use the default external encoding*

In this case the inspect-command gets a UTF-8 character (Not ASCII), but the default encoding seems to be another.
The default encoding can be read in `Encoding.default_external`.

To avoid the error you must encode the result of inspect:

```
#encoding: utf-8
class Text
  def initialize(txt)
    @txt = txt
  end
  def inspect
    #force ASCII and replace invalid/undefined characters
    ("<Text: %s>" % @txt).encode('ASCII', :undef => :replace, :invalid => :replace)
  end
end

p Text.new('Hä, was soll das?') #-> <Text: H?, was soll das?>
```

Instead of `ASCII` in `encode` you can use also `Encoding.default_external`:

```
("<Text: %s>" % @txt).encode(Encoding.default_external, :undef => :replace)
```